# connect several QSliders to one Slot

Tags: python, qt

How should I connect 5 QtSliders to just one Slot?, I would need to know which one of them sent the signal "valueChanged", thus, I somehow would need to send anything like "objectName".

I do not know any propper way to do that, I have done that so far:

```
for index, child in enumerate(self.ui.groupBox_2.children()):
    try:        
        child.connect(child,SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), child,SLOT("valueChangedSlot(int,child.objectName)"))

    except Exception:
        pass
```

Nothing is happening, Im not getting any error, just nothing is happening when moving the Slide.

I forgot to post also the slot:

```
@pyqtSlot(int, str)
def valueChangedSlot(self,value,name):    
    print value, name
```

Comment: qsignalmapper is made for this

Comment: @ratchetfreak QSignalMapper will not work in this case since he process signal with extra argument.

Comment: yeah that's right, I am thinking in functools.partial, but I do not know how to use it yet

Answer (score 3):

To get who sent the signal you should call method `sender()`.

```
  @pyqtSlot(int)
  def supportSlot(self, newValue) :
    slider = self.sender()
    name = slider.objectName()
    self.valueChangedSlot(newvalue, name) # calling your original slot
```

Comment: oh thanks, looks simple and easy, didn't know anything about this "sender" method. THANKS!